# How to show Windows Form Element Host's Message Box as Modal?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, messagebox, elementhost

I have windows form application in C#.
I have class library for WPF user control. And I am using that in Windows Form App using Element Host. Now in WPF User control i need to show one message using MessageBox. it's working but displayed modeless on Main Form of Windows Form Application. I want to Show this Message box as model.

Any help please.

Edits:

let me Explain by example:
I have “WindowsFormApp1”
Another is “WPFUserCtrlLib” which is class library. And it has UserControl named as “WPFUserCtrl” so I have “WPFUserCtrl.xaml” and “WPFUserCtrl.xaml.cs” Files.
In WindowsFormApp1 I have MainForm named “Form1”. In Form1 I am using “WPFUserCtrl” using Element Host.
Now there is some logic resides in “WPFUserCtrl.xaml.cs” say

```
String ErrorMsg=“Error There”;
if(condition)
{
//Do Task
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show(ErrorMsg);
}
```

So here I need to show ErrorMsg. When this MessageBox is displayed, it is modeless as I am able to access controls on “Form1” like menus, buttons and all.

Comment: Can you please show the code, how you display the modal window in WPF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ShowDialog and ElementHost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387382/wpf-showdialog-and-elementhost)

Comment: Hello derape, Thank you for help. I have visited the link posted by you but i think my question is some what different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried lot. Couldn't get solution so posted question here and continued to try again with diff approach. And Now I found the solution.

Solution is: use Dispatcher.Invoke

```
if(condition)
{
    //Do Task
}
else
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
                MessageBox.Show(ErrorMsg);
            })
            );
}
```

Now my MessageBox is model.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the owner of the WPF window to the winforms window?

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhendersblog/archive/2005/10/04/476921.aspx) link that is necessary in order to make the modal dialog work within winforms.

```
var window = new WpfWindow(); 

var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
helper.Owner = this.Handle; 

window.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Hello,  Thank you @derape, this is useful as i had same issue (another then this issue) which is there in that link posted by you so solved my that issue. :)